# Do monk AoE abilities count as hits for "Life on Hit" items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm wondering if hits inflicted by abilities doing AoE damage (in particular the Monks [Sweeping Wind](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/sweeping-wind) and [Crippling Wave](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/crippling-wave)) count as hits for "Life on Hit" properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do, however, there does seem to be some sort of reduction in the effectiveness of vampiric effects when triggered by area-effect spells. The exact amount varies, but this is easy to verify in game if you switch between a single target and area spell.

Answer (score 0):

They do indeed.  The best way to see this working is to turn on "Show Healing" in the options menu and perform the AoE skills.  Unfortunately I can't get you a screenshot of this right now, but hope this helps!

Comment: There don't seem to be any healing popups for any healing caused by "Life on Hit" items.