# Do Sweeping Wind - Cyclone tornados still proc Life on Hit?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

In 2012 Diablo III builds, the Monk's Cyclones generated from Sweeping Wind were considered damage from you rather than summons, and so they proc'd Life on Hit (confirmed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72091/does-sweeping-wind-activate-resolve)). Is that still the case in 2.1? If so, is the proc coefficient or life gain effect reduced in some way, as suggested [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70239/do-monk-aoe-abilities-count-as-hits-for-life-on-hit-items)?

Note: I know the Sweeping Wind itself doesn't proc (at least last I checked), I'm only asking about the Cyclones.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding the answer is no.  Since it is not attached to you and is more a summoned entity, the ability to gain any effects that you would normally gain on strike(Freeze on Hit, Stun on Hit, Fear) are not part of the cyclone.  It would be the same as if you were on a Demon Hunter and dropped a Sentry.  Since Sentries do not gain any effects, the same would be aplied to Cyclones and even Mystic Allies.